# .png images display in IE8 alone but not inside a page

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, png

It's been a while since I did serious web development. Now I meet a host of brand new problems I'm no longer familiar with..

I have some .png images for various icons in my web page. What I find is that whenever I edit these images, they stop working inside a page in IE8. That is, they (usually) display OK when I first open the page, then are replaced by the placeholder icon on refresh. Sometimes, some of the icons display and others, with the same src, don't.

My image tags are nothing fancy, typically:

```
<img src="images/misc/smallreport.png" alt="Report" />
```

When I right-click an icon in the page and select "properties", protocol, type, address and size are shown as "Not Available", and dimensions are incorrect (size of the placeholder, I bet).

If I open the images directly in IE (ie. not within the page), they work just fine.

I have used Paint.NET to edit the images, but have also tried saving them with Paint.

Right now, I am working right off the hard disk (ie. not through a web server). And, oh yes, none of this happens in Google Chrome.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we learn something new every day..

I mentioned that I'm running this directly off the harddisk? Now, it turns out the html page (which I had gotten off a coworker) was blocked "to help protect my computer", as Windows does.

This is no big surprise, lots of files I'm working with originate on other computers, and I usually don't worry much about it (except with executables, which won't run until unblocked).

It seems, however, that when IE8 loads such a blocked HTML file, its security settings adjust somehow, and - well, I can only guess at the details, but as soon as I right-clicked the HTML file, selected Properties and clicked the "unblock" button, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

check the path to the file is correct - can we see the  tag please.

Comment: The path is correct - after all, the images display sometimes. I have included a tag in the question.

Comment: have you checked Tools>internet options>advanced> and see if the show images box is checked

Comment: could also try Try Internet Options > General tab > Settings (under Browser history) > make it so its "Everytime I visit the web page".

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me once, I tried hard to find what was wrong, then I realized I was saving (from Photoshop) the file as PSD but with extension .png. Make sure you're not doing the same.

Also:

- Clear temporary Internet files
- Verify that the Show Pictures option has not been turned off
- Make sure that the Toggle Images.exe Web accessory is not present and disabling images
- Make sure that a third-party Internet security, firewall, or cookie-blocking program is not causing the problem
- Enable the Auto-Select encoding option

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283807)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the website you have browse has a lack of support
for an IE browser. IE is a nightmare for all web developers & Web designers.
It might be the developer of that website didn't care for an IE display because 
of IE issues. Perhaps IE is trying to create a web standard to increase their
sales and marketing strategy. That's why don't care the modern Web development standard.
Why Chrome or Firefox or Safari, it's a free anyway.